# Does anyone knows how to use AWSRekognition SDK in order to detect faces in images in swift 4?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I already integrated the AWSRekognitionthem into my project. and I make sure I'm  connected to AWS, by this code

```
import AWSCore
      //. . .
AWSDDLog.add(AWSDDTTYLogger.sharedInstance)
AWSDDLog.sharedInstance.logLevel = .info
```

and the respnse is

> Welcome to AWS! You are connected successfully

but when I write this line it give me an error

```
let rekognitionClient = AWSRekognition.defaultRekognition()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
    `let rekognitionClient = AWSRekognition.default()`
and see if that works!